# Can I have more than 1 form action(form inside form) in single jsp using hibernate

Tags: spring, forms, hibernate, jsp, action

In this jsp, I have used 2 form actions, one to save the role(table:defining role), and other to call the drop list from other table(table: solutionList).

After clicking on submit, it is not doing anything.

If i remove this form(solutionMaster.html)

Im getting this error "  Invalid property 'sMName' of bean class [com.mode;.definingrole]: Bean property 'sMName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?.

Yes, I know the reason, Because the column 'sMName' was not the part of defining role table. what to do with this.

The Thing i want to know is,

1. Can we create form inside form?

2.Without creating another form, How can i get the column values of other table to defining role table?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.!!!

```
  <div class="modal inmodal" id="myModalForRole" tabindex="-1"
                    role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                </button>
                                <i class="fa fa-laptop modal-icon"></i>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Define Role</h4>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form:form action="newRoleDetails.html" method="post"
                                    commandName="deftemp" id="deftemp">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <form:form action="solutionName.html" method="post"
                                                commandName="soltemp" id="soltemp"> 
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <label>Solutions*</label><br>


                                                <form:select path="sMName" class="form-control"
                                                    id="sMName">
                                                    <form:option value="" label="--select--"></form:option>
                                                    <c:forEach var="solutionList" items="${solutionList}"
                                                        varStatus="loop">
                                                        <form:option value="${solutionList}"
                                                            label="${solutionList}">
                                                        </form:option>
                                                    </c:forEach>
                                                </form:select>
                                            </div>
                                             </form:form> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <label>Parent Role*</label><br>
                                                <form:textarea path="ParentRole" id="ParentRole"
                                                    class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Parent Role" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <label>Sub Role*</label><br>
                                                <form:textarea path="SubRole" id="SubRole"
                                                    class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Child role" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white"
                                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form:form>
                            </div>
```

Models: (solutionlist.java)

```
package com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table (name="solutionlist")
public class solutionlist implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="solutionId",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED INT(4)")
    Integer solutionId;

    @Column(name="solutionName")
    String solutionName;

    @Column(name="solutionOwner")
    String solutionOwner;

    @Column(name="ownerMailId")
    String ownerMailId;

    @Column(name="additionDate")
    String additionDate;

    public Integer getSolutionId() {
        return solutionId;
    }

    public void setSolutionId(Integer solutionId) {
        this.solutionId = solutionId;
    }

    public String getSolutionName() {
        return solutionName;
    }

    public void setSolutionName(String solutionName) {
        this.solutionName = solutionName;
    }

    public String getSolutionOwner() {
        return solutionOwner;
    }

    public void setSolutionOwner(String solutionOwner) {
        this.solutionOwner = solutionOwner;
    }

    public String getOwnerMailId() {
        return ownerMailId;
    }

    public void setOwnerMailId(String ownerMailId) {
        this.ownerMailId = ownerMailId;
    }

    public String getAdditionDate() {
        return  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss.SSS")
        .format(new Date());
    }

    public void setAdditionDate(String additionDate) {
        this.additionDate = additionDate;
    }
}
```

definingrole.java

```
package com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="definingrole")
public class definingrole implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="SNo")
    Integer SNo;

    @Column(name="Solutions")
    String Solutions;

    @Column(name="ParentRole")
    String ParentRole;

    @Column(name="SubRole")
    String SubRole;

    public Integer getSNo() {
        return SNo;
    }

    public void setSNo(Integer sNo) {
        SNo = sNo;
    }

    public String getSolutions() {
        return Solutions;
    }

    public void setSolutions(String solutions) {
        Solutions = solutions;
    }

    public String getParentRole() {
        return ParentRole;
    }

    public void setParentRole(String parentRole) {
        ParentRole = parentRole;
    }

    public String getSubRole() {
        return SubRole;
    }

    public void setSubRole(String subRole) {
        SubRole = subRole;
    }
}
```

Controller : newRoleDetails.html

```
@RequestMapping(value=NEWROLEDETAILS_PATH)
    public String newRoleDetails(Map<String, Object> model, definingrole value,solutionlist sol) throws Exception {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName();
        String nameOfUser=TemplateService.getEmpNameOfUser(name);
        model.put("nameOfUser",nameOfUser);
        String userid=loginService.getUserId();
        String role=loginService.getRole(); 

        TemplateService.newRoleDetails(value);
        definingrole deftemp=new definingrole();
        model.put("deftemp", deftemp);
        solutionlist s = new solutionlist();

        ArrayList<templateDetails> listOfTemplate=TemplateService.listTemplateDetails(role,userid);
        model.put("listOfTemplate",listOfTemplate);
            return TEMPLATESUMMARY;
    }
```

controller : solutionName.html

```
@RequestMapping("/solutionlist.html")
    public String solutionName(Map<String, Object> model,solutionlist sol) throws Exception {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName();
        String nameOfUser=TemplateService.getEmpNameOfUser(name);
        model.put("nameOfUser",nameOfUser);
        solutionlist soltemp = new solutionlist();
        model.put("soltemp", soltemp);
        ArrayList<String> solutionList=TemplateService.getSolutionListForTemplate();
        model.put("solutionList", solutionList);
        return REDIRECT_TEMPLATESUMMARY_URL;
    }
```

Comment: Please Help......Stuck with this code for a day..... :(

Comment: Please explain what do you need to do? and give the detail of your controller and models. form inside form is not make any sense. Seems like your situation is not straight forward. You have to make a way around.

Comment: I didn't get the point of why do you need a form for `select` list

Comment: I have added controller and models here. I am storing the role details to db. I am fetching drop-list from other table(solutionlist), based on droplist, i l enter parent and subrole, and it will store in definingRole(table) - @Zico

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have nested forms per https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions

Comment: Then.. Is there any way to get values from other table to the form? - @SeanCarroll

Comment: Like @Zico I'm having trouble understanding what you are attempting to do.  All you want to do is populate solutionList correct? If thats true why cant you call TemplateService.getSolutionListForTemplate and populate your solution list in newRoleDetails? Also, it appears your form:select is wrong. You have solutionList1 as both the items and the var variable

Comment: sorry, i changed to solutionlist, but failed to update here. I have tried that idea, by calling service.func, but its showing error.. as i mentioned earlier

Comment: In short, you need to populate the `<select>` options with values right? Which you are trying to get from `/solutionlist.html`. Am I right?

Comment: The error regarding sMName is because that field doesn't actually exist on definingrole.

Comment: My advice would be to use a form/command object instead of attempting to use your definingrole entity

Comment: Yes .. from solutionlist i need to fetch the values - @Zico

Comment: Yes. Its showing the error as you said. But I am not clear with ur advice. Can you please explain in detail??

Comment: I can set up a chat room which might be better but essentially instead of binding your form to definingrole create some form/command object that has all the fields required by your form, which can include a field sMName. When the form is posted you will model bind to that command object and then map appropriately to your entities

Comment: In your `definingrole ` class the field `Solutions` will hold the single single String from List of `solutionList ` or you need the whole list into the single String field?

Comment: @BhuvanaK I am giving you an answer to get the value of ArrayList to your `select` options as value. And will bind to the `definingrole ` class as `Solution`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are trying to populate list inside form under the tag of `form`. Which is wrong approach. You won't get the value from `/solutionlist.html` by your `form`. You have to call at least a `GET` if you want to use `/solutionlist.html` controller.**

If i think So then you have to do the following

1. You don't need the '/solutionlist.html' controller.
2. Just bind the ArrayList `solutionList` into model in the controller method where the form page served. I mean the `GET` method of Controller where the given form is served.

   `ArrayList<String> solutionList=TemplateService.getSolutionListForTemplate();
    model.put("solutionList", solutionList);`
3. You will get that `solutionList` directly to your form as value. So, modify the `select` part of your form as follows

   `<select name="solutions"path="Solutions">
       <c:forEach items="${solutionList}" var="solution">
         <option value="${solution}">${solution}</option>
       </c:forEach>
   </select>`

Comment: Hi @Zico, I have been struggling with this for 2 days. Now Its working... Thanks. Values are getting stored in defining role table except solutionList. So, I have set the selected solutionList to the object of definingRole model like " value.setSolutions(sol.getSolutionName())" (SolutionList sol). I have used two forms in many jsp to get droplist from other tables. This will be very useful to reduce my code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thanks @Zico